# SpagoBI/BIRT JDBC connection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, birt, spagobi

I made a Datasource connection in SpagoBI using JDBC connection [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver ( v5.0)]
Connection is succesfull.Then I start to build a new data set. I could see all the tables in my database. But when I click Preview Results I am getting error.

Error happened while running the report:

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.DatasetPreviewTask.doRun(DatasetPreviewTask.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.DatasetPreviewTask.runDataset(DatasetPreviewTask.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.DatasetPreviewTask.execute(DatasetPreviewTask.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.DataSetPreviewer.preview(DataSetPreviewer.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.ResultSetPreviewPage$5.run(ResultSetPreviewPage.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.OdaDataException: Cannot get the result set metadata.
    org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: SQL statement does not return a ResultSet object.
SQL error #1:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=500' at line 1
 ;
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=500' at line 1
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ExceptionHandler.newException(ExceptionHandler.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ExceptionHandler.throwException(ExceptionHandler.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ExceptionHandler.throwException(ExceptionHandler.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.getRuntimeMetaData(PreparedStatement.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.getProjectedColumns(PreparedStatement.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.doGetMetaData(PreparedStatement.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSourceQuery.execute(DataSourceQuery.java:964)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery$OdaDSQueryExecutor.executeOdiQuery(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.execute(QueryExecutor.java:1142)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ServiceForQueryResults.executeQuery(ServiceForQueryResults.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryResults.getResultIterator(QueryResults.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryResults.getResultMetaData(QueryResults.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.DatasetPreviewTask.extractQuery(DatasetPreviewTask.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.DatasetPreviewTask.doRun(DatasetPreviewTask.java:126)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: SQL statement does not return a ResultSet object.
SQL error #1:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=500' at line 1
 ;
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=500' at line 1
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Statement.getMetaUsingPolicy1(Statement.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Statement.getMetaData(Statement.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.bidi.BidiStatement.getMetaData(BidiStatement.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaQuery.doGetMetaData(OdaQuery.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaQuery.getMetaData(OdaQuery.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.getRuntimeMetaData(PreparedStatement.java:407)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=500' at line 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3206)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1447)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:460)
    ... 22 more
```

My MySQL Query is

```
SELECT * FROM customers
```

I am using SpagoBIStudio_5.1.0_win64_19012015, Java 1.7

Comment: what is your MySQL version?

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=462850

DOWNLOADS this driver and use it in your connection when you create your datasouce

and the blem is solved

Comment: Ok, this may solve a problem, but... you really could provide more explanation. [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: really ok    if you need any help when you resolve that probleme you can post it and i help you

Comment: Please write answers as compete as possible, and do read Help Centre...

Comment: OK ok ok ok ok ok